# open graph tags are not rendering when sharing a video

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, posting

We are using koala gem for sharing posts on fan page in Ruby on Rails. We are running a video site and we share video page using Open graph tag on fan page wall. Sometime all meta-tags renders and sometime only shared link appear. We have also checked the page output here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object and tags were coming properly.

Our Open graph meta tags details are as follows

```
Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="434628296582427" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="&quot;Troy&quot; now playing at theater action1-movies" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:description" content="Junaid Confiz is selling tickets for this video via video. The ticket is $10.99 and runtime is 00:00:05" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:duration" content="0:0:5/" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:height" content="360" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:width" content="452" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="http://videos.herokuapp.com/videos/121/public_facing" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video" content="http://videos.herokuapp.com/swf_player/player_dev.swf?watch=121" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="videos.herokuapp.com/swf_player/player_dev.swf?watch=121" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="https://videos.s3.amazonaws.com:443/processed_videos/89164f30-5f13-0130-2b8c-22000a960075/VPLAYER_640x480_0000.jpg?Signature=xZGqiGmILoAeixL9s7k4M73o8u4%3D&amp;Expires=1361621718&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIUV57OFPRFFEJSTQ" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

There is no problem in rendering of page as we have also checked that. Did anyone observe such a random behaviour. If you share same video page url on two fan-pages then it don't render properly on page 1 and render correctly on other page while facebook send us only one request.